# Expanding a range of phone numbers in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, auto-generate

I have a table with phone numbers.  One column has the first number in a range.  The next column has the last four digits in that range.  How do I create a row for each individual number?

Example:
    202-366-1234 (phone number from)
    next column has 1240 (phone number to)

I would like to have each phone number on a separate row. So they would look like this.

```
202-366-1234
202-366-1235
202-366-1236
202-366-1237
202-366-1238
202-366-1239
202-366-1240
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you will have to this programmatically using VBA. Do you want to store these records or want only for display purpose?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I will want to store the records.

Answer (score 2):

Create a variation of a typical "numbers" table to hold all of the possible last-four-digits, e.g.

```
[PhoneSuffix]

suffix
------
0000
0001
0002
...
9998
9999
```

then for an input table like this

```
[Table1]

ID  PhoneFrom     PhoneTo
--  ------------  -------
 1  202-366-1234  1240
 2  416-555-1212  1221
```

you could use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT Left(t1.PhoneFrom, 8) & ps.suffix AS PhoneNo
FROM Table1 t1, PhoneSuffix ps
WHERE ps.suffix Between Right(t1.PhoneFrom, 4) And t1.PhoneTo
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fancy Cartesian (multiplying) query which doesn't require new tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Id, 
    Left([StartNumber],8) & CStr(Val(Right([StartNumber],4))+[Factor]) AS PhoneNumber
FROM 
    msysobjects AS Uno, 
    msysobjects AS Deca
WHERE 
    (((10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10))<=Val([EndNumber])-Val(Right([StartNumber],4))));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this will a loop and not have to create a numbers table?  I now have the table named PHONES in that table is a field with the staring Phone number and a field with the ending phone number (no dashes just the 10 digit number).  So I want a query that would take PhoneNumberStart = 2023661234 (one field) and PhoneNumberEnd = 2023661238 (second field) and have it return 2023661235, 2023661236, 2023661237.  Thanks for any input.

Comment: There is no new numbers table. And if you now have plain 10-digit numbers, just use `StartNumber` _as is_ and not the sanitizing expression.